# Using Firestore in Vue, .where doesn't return any results - but they exist

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm pretty new to firestore. I've got this query that shows chat messages and updates when new ones appear. I only want the current user (school) to see messages from their own school. If I don't contain the .where clause - it shows all the messages, but nothing shows up if I use it (even though they exist)

Here is a link to an image of my firestore page (since I can't embed it):

[image]

I call the method on mount:

```
mounted() {
  //fetches the messages
  this.fetchMessages(this.$route.params.id);
},
```

Then the method is:

```
fetchMessages(schoolsIdentification) {
  db.collection('chat')
    .where("user.schoolId", "array-contains", schoolsIdentification)
    .orderBy('date')
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      let allMessages = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        allMessages.push(doc.data())
      })
      console.log("the all messages array length is:", allMessages.length)
      this.messages = allMessages;
    })
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter expects that `user.schoolId` is an array:

```
.where("user.schoolId", "array-contains", schoolsIdentification)
```

But it's not an array - it's just a string.  If you want to filter on a string field that could contain several different possible values, you should use an "in" query instead, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any).

> Use the `in` operator to combine up to 10 equality (`==`) clauses on the same field with a logical OR. An in query returns documents where the given field matches any of the comparison values.

```
.where("user.schoolId", "in", schoolsIdentification)
```

Comment: Hmm, it's now saying: 

"FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Invalid Query. A non-empty array is required for 'in' filters." 

Is it possible to just query the 'user' array with 'array-contains'?

Comment: I managed to get it fixed by changing my .where query to:
.where("user.schoolId", "==", schoolsIdentification)
Then I had to build a composite (because I'm sorting by date as well). Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, it's customary on Stack Overflow to upvote and mark it as correct using the buttons to the left of the answer above.